# Extracting the link from a website to google spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath

The thing I need to extract to google spreadsheet is "35,958". Do you have any idea how to do it ? It's `li` and there are duplicates in the code:

```
<ul class="stats">
 <li><a class="density" href="/vsearch/p?f_N=S&amp;f_CC=1382&amp;trk=extra_biz_second_deg_connected">157</a> <span>second&#45;degree connections</span></li>
 <li><a class="density" href="/vsearch/p?f_CC=1382&amp;trk=extra_biz_employees_deg_connected">35,958</a> <span>Employees on LinkedIn</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to get the last `li` element from the `ul`:

```
//ul[@class = "stats"]/li[last()]/a/text()
```

Another option would be to get the `span` element by text and retrieve the preceding `a` element:

```
//span[. = "Employees on LinkedIn"]/preceding-sibling::a/text()
```

And there are certainly more options.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... Do you have any idea what might be wrong ? Thanks in advance @alecxe !